# 很多的 + noun vs 很多 + noun

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between 很多的 and 很多? Here are some examples:

- 他们在这个乌代布尔地区做了**很多的**调查
- 比如说攒**很多的**钱买一个LV的包
- 为什么有时候人会在人**很多的**地方觉得自己很寂寞？

Is 的 needed in all three sentences?

Comment: 的 is redundant in 很多的. Just use 很多

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Basically, `的` can always be omitted for a simple adjective.
2. But for emphasis of the adjective, `的` is added (so omit it if not).
3. For the omission of `的`, check [this link](https://www.zhihu.com/question/24860134), kind of CN quora (if it is fine to read).
4. The third sentence is an exception of your description. `很多` comes after `人`, so it is `(人很多)的地方` and `的` cannot be omitted here to avoid ambiguity.